# Creating a task wrapper around an existing object

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have a method which returns a Task where the implementation may or may not need to perform a slow operation in order to retrieve the result.  I would like to be able to simply wrap the result value into a Task which is marked as having completed synchronously in the case where the value is already available.  Today I have something like this:

```
public Task<Foo> GetFooAsync(int key) {
  lock(this) {
    if(_Cache.ContainsKey(key) ) {
      Task<Foo> ret = new Task<Foo>(()=>_Cache[key]);
      ret.RunSynchronously();
      return ret;
    }
    else {
      return Task.Factory.StartNew<Foo>(SomethingSlow());
    }
  }
}
```

Is there is simpler way to do this that doesn't require me to construct the task with a delegate when I already know the result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx):

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Foo>();
tcs.SetResult(_Cache[key]);
return tcs.Task;
```

(Note that if `_Cache` is a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you could use `TryGetValue` to make it a single lookup.)

Answer (score 50):

Beginning with .NET 4.5, you can use the [`Task.FromResult<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method for exactly this purpose:

```
return Task.FromResult(_Cache[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a synchronous version of the method that returns the result you can do the following

```
Task<String>(()=> Hello(Name));
```

The hello method would look like below.

```
public String Hello(String Name)
{
   return "Hello " + Name;
}
```